Is it good to add all targeting countries content in one blog?
I currently have a blog for each subdomain and half of its content is the same. So, after auditing the website I found the content is not performing well.
I'm thinking of creating one blog to the root domain and making the navigation easy to let users choose news for the specific country in that main menu from the category.
Do you think this is the best approach regarding SEO and UX?
If you can can share a better example that would be great.

Have you got hreflang tags set up?  Your existing configuration should be fine as long as Google know what's going on.

Yes, and I'm already using canonical for duplicate content but it's not working as I wished as content performance on my site is bad
